# google maps not accepting events

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I can create a map and set markers but when I try to zoom or move the map with the mouse nothing happens.

Here is my function

```
function initMap() {
var locations = $scope.locList ? $scope.locList : {loc: {loc: {lat: $scope.data.loc.lat, lng: $scope.data.loc.lng}}};
var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
  zoom: $scope.locList ? 4 : 16,
  center: $scope.locList ? new google.maps.LatLng(39.833, -98.583) : new google.maps.LatLng($scope.data.loc.lat, $scope.data.loc.lng),
  scrollwheel: false
});
map.addListener('click', function(e) {
  map.set('scrollwheel', true);
});
map.addListener('mouseout', function(e) {
  map.set('scrollwheel', false);
});
var marker;
$.each(locations, function(key, value){
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(value.loc.lat, value.loc.lng),
    icon: $scope.data.marker,
    map: map
  });
})
}
```

and my markup

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

This all happens after `$scope.locList` and `$scope.data` are populated

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you are not able to zoom because you are initializing your map with `scrollwheel: false` and you are trying to set `scrollwheel: true` when you click on the map.

Instead, you should attach `scrollwheel: true` on `mouseover`, same thing for `draggable: true`:

```
map.addListener('mouseover', function(e) {
   map.set('scrollwheel', true);
   map.set('draggable', true);
});
```

Then, on `mouseout`, you set them false again:

```
map.addListener('mouseout', function(e) {
    map.set('scrollwheel', false);
    map.set('draggable', false);
});
```

This is how you should initialize your map:

```
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.9026329,12.452200400000038);
    var mapOptions = {
                        center: myLatLng,
                        zoom: 5,
                        scrollwheel: false,
                        draggable: false,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                     };

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(attributes.id), mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                          position: myLatLng,
                                          map: map,
                                          title:"My town"
                 });

marker.setMap(map);
```

[This is a working Plunker that reproduces your target](http://plnkr.co/edit/A8RfIGoCCFvsHk7Dfsw6?p=preview)

Hope I've been helpful.